# MySQL syntax error?

Tags: python, mysql, database

I have searched on forums for the error I keep getting when running my code but it seems to be situation specific.
My program connects to a database, and takes a line from a text file, extracts the name from the line, and uses that name to do a search query in the database. The following is the relevant code:

```
while line:
    lines = line.split('\t')
    if len(lines) > 1:
        date = lines[0]
        name = lines[2]
        address = lines[3]
        amount = int(float(lines[len(lines)-1]))
        named = name.split()
        first = named[1]
        last = named[0]
        zipc = lines[4]
        cur.execute("SELECT `Date`, `Contrib`, `Amount`, `Street`, `City`
        `State`, `Zip` FROM indiv_contribs WHERE Contrib = '%s, %s'" %
        (last, first))
        rows = cur.fetchall()
```

The error I keep getting is:

> "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'malley, matthew'' at line 1"

Comment: For starters, you've got no comma between the `City` and `State` columns. I imagine that doesn't help.

Comment: Does your input contain any double-quotes? You'll need to filter those so they don't end up in (last, first).

Comment: Can you also print out what last, first contain? It's possible that `matthew` could have a `'` character in there

Comment: You can find out the problem by simply printing that SQL statement.

Comment: And, instead of performing the string formatting yourself, perhaps switch to using defined parameters, as in this example http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples.  Let's the driver handle any escaping issues etc that might be tripping you up at the moment.

Comment: sorry, there is a comma in the original code between City and State, it got deleted when I was formatting the question

Answer (score 3):

If your language is Python, your SQL statement should look like:

```
cur.execute("""SELECT Date, Contrib, Amount, Street, City, State, Zip FROM indiv_contribs WHERE Contrib = %s, %s""", (last, first))
rows = cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: That won't do, as I suppose that `Contrib` is a column containing last name and first name. Better do `cur.execute("""SELECT Date, Contrib, Amount, Street, City, State, Zip FROM indiv_contribs WHERE Contrib = %s""", (last + ", " + first,))`

Comment: thanks glglgl! I tried AShelly's way frist but still received the error but it went away after stringing the last and first name together.